# ThreadpoolExecutor with retry capability and shutdown after a task fails for a number of times

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, runnable, threadpoolexecutor

I have a need of a threadpool executor, which needs to complete an exact number (same) tasks.

It has to be able to re-submit failed tasks for an n number of times. If any of the tasks fail for more than n, then the threadpool should shutdown and not continue to process any other tasks.

I have tried to combine 2 approaches which I've found in different answers - one for re-submitting failed tasks by overriding ThreadPoolExecutor.afterExecute, and subclassing CountDownLatch so that threads waiting on the latch get interrupted and the executor shuts down.

So far, this is the subclassed countdown latch:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class AbortableCountDownLatch extends CountDownLatch {
protected boolean aborted = false;

public AbortableCountDownLatch(int count) {
    super(count);
}

/**
 * Unblocks all threads waiting on this latch and cause them to receive an
 * AbortedException.  If the latch has already counted all the way down,
 * this method does nothing.
 */
public void abort() {
    if( getCount() == 0 )
        return;

    this.aborted = true;
    while(getCount() > 0)
        countDown();
}

@Override
public boolean await(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {
    final boolean rtrn = super.await(timeout,unit);
    if (aborted)
        throw new AbortedException();
    return rtrn;
}

@Override
public void await() throws InterruptedException {
    super.await();
    if (aborted)
        throw new AbortedException();
}


public static class AbortedException extends InterruptedException {
    public AbortedException() {
    }

    public AbortedException(String detailMessage) {
        super(detailMessage);
    }
}
}
```

And the thread pool executor:

```
public class MyThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {

private static final int RETRY_LIMIT = 3;

private Map<Runnable, Integer> retriedTasks = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
private AbortableCountDownLatch latch;

public MyThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime,
                            TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue, AbortableCountDownLatch latch) {
    super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue);
    this.latch = latch;
}

@Override
public void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
    super.afterExecute(r, t);
    // If submit() method is called instead of execute()
    if (t == null && r instanceof Future<?>) {
        try {
            Object result = ((Future<?>) r).get();
        } catch (CancellationException e) {
            t = e;
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            t = e.getCause();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
    if (t != null) {
        retriedTasks.put(r, retriedTasks.getOrDefault(r, 0) + 1);
        System.out.println("Retries for " + r + " -> " + retriedTasks.get(r));
        /* check to see if we have retried this task too many times, if so - shutdown */
        if (retriedTasks.containsKey(r) && retriedTasks.get(r) > RETRY_LIMIT) {
            System.err.println("Thread failed for more than " + RETRY_LIMIT + " times, aborting everything..");
            this.latch.abort();
        } else {
            System.err.println("Thread threw  exception " + t.getMessage() + ". Retry-ing task...");
            execute(r);
        }
    } else {
        /* clear any previous retry count for this runnable */
        retriedTasks.remove(r);
    }
}
}
```

And a main would be using them like this:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MainProcessor {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    AbortableCountDownLatch latch = new AbortableCountDownLatch(5);
    ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = new MyThreadPoolExecutor(8, 8, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(), latch);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        threadPoolExecutor.submit(() -> {
            System.out.println("Started thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            Random random = new Random();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(7000));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                if (random.nextBoolean()){
                    System.err.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " failed - throwing exception..");
                    throw new RuntimeException("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "failed! spectacularly :!");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " finished.");
                    latch.countDown();
                }
        });
    }

    try {
        latch.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        threadPoolExecutor.shutdownNow();
    }

    threadPoolExecutor.shutdown();
}
}
```

Does this approach look correct? I don't particularly like that the latch has to be passed to both the thread pool executor and to the actual Runnable. Is there a standard way of achieving this? I am fine with a Scala version too.

I have seen others who suggest that the tasks should re-submit itself to the pool in case of failure, but that doesn't seem a good idea, as the task should only be responsible of the actual running logic, and not execution details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a Task-Wrapper that does the work, then it would be rather simple:

```java
public class TaskWrapper implements Runnable
{
    private Runnable task;
    private int maxResubmits;
    private ThreadPoolExecutor executor;
    private CountDownLatch latch;

    public TaskWrapper(Runnable task, int maxResubmits, ThreadPoolExecutor executor, CountDownLatch latch) {
        this.task=task;
        this.maxResubmits=maxResubmits;
        this.executor=executor;
        this.latch=latch;
        executor.submit(this);
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            task.run();
            latch.countdoun();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            maxResubmits--;
            if(maxResubmits>0)
                executor.submit(this);
            else
            {
                latch.countdoun();
                executor.shutdownNow()
            }                
        }
    }
}
```

You now only need to create the latch, call your tasks and then wait for the execution:

```java
List<Runnable> tasks;
int maxResubmits;

CountDownLatch latch=new CountDownLatch(tasks.size());

tasks.forEach(task->new TaskWrapper(task,maxResubmits,executor,latch));

latch.await();

if(!executor.isShutdown())
    executor.shutdown();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. With this approach - does the original task even need to be a Runnable at all? In theory it could be anything, as it's not run in a thread of its own, right?

And what about a latch - would it be required at all here? I do need to make sure all individual tasks successfully completed, exactly once each. Would the outside code which creates all the TaskWrapers call executor.shutdown() at the end?

Comment: I have incorporated the latch. And you can use any object or function call. ``Runnable`` is just for simplicity.